# DELETE facebook post using FQL

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook4j

I am using a facebook4j api for connecting to facebook. My aim is to fetch and delete the posts posted on my wall by friends. I am searching for FQL (Delete query) for facebook post.
Question : Delete facebook posts from java using FQL or any other technique

Comment: what is your actual question?

Answer (score 1):

You can delete facebook wall post by using graph api, [Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/post) is the documentation available.